# Is this (set-)difference of spaces of functions nonempty?

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $g_y$ be a family of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, indexed by $y\in [0,1]$, such that $(x,y)\to g_y(x)$ is also continuous.

Denote the set of all such families that additionally fulfill  $y|g_y(x_1)-g_y(x_2)| \leq |x_1 -x_2| $, for all $x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]$ and $y\neq 0$, by $U$.
Denote similarly the set of all such families that also fulfill  $H(y) |g_y(x_1)-g_y(x_2)| \leq |x_1 -x_2| $, for all $x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]$ and for *some* $H$ for which $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{H(y)}dy$ is finite, by $V$.

Is it true that $U\setminus V$ is nonempty ?

**What I tried:** Finding a family that is not in $V$: If we divide, $\frac{1}{H(y)}$ bounds the slope of the segment connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$, so a family not in $V$ would either have infinite slope at some function from the family (as does, for example, $\sqrt(x)$ exhibits, which has a cusp at 0) or infinite $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{H(y)}dy$ for any upper bound  $\frac{1}{H(y)}$ of the slope. (How are these conditions connected to each-other ? Or is it possible for one to be true, but for the other one to fail ?)
But since it should also be in $U$, the "infinite slope" failure can't actually happen for any $y\neq 0$, because to be in $U$, the slope has to be bounded by $\frac{1}{y}$.
Because of the requirement of $(x,y)\to g_y(x)$ being  continuous at $y=0$, I would venture to guess that we have to design a family of functions where "infinite slope" occurs *only* at $y=0$. If that were not true that, then one  would have to use the integral: But if all the slopes are finite on the compact set $[0,1]$ I imagine it must be possible to also find an $H(y)$, such that the integral is finite.
So it seems that $U\setminus V$ can only be nonempty if we can construct such a family with a cusp at $y=0$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @zhoraster See my edit.